# Unicorn, can't restart: "rack and Rack::Builder must be available for processing config.ru"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, capistrano, unicorn, digital-ocean

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 server with nginx and unicorn. I have deployed a Rails application with capistrano to `/home/rails/myapp`.

When trying to restart unicorn with `sudo service unicorn restart` I get the following:

```
* Restarting Unicorn web server unicorn
rack not available, functionality reduced
rack and Rack::Builder must be available for processing config.ru
```

I'm getting a 502 from nginx when trying to access the site in my browser.

Here's my /etc/default/unicorn file:

```
# Change paramentres below to appropriate values and set CONFIGURED to yes.
CONFIGURED=yes

# Default timeout until child process is killed during server upgrade,
# it has *no* relation to option "timeout" in server's config.rb.
TIMEOUT=60

# Path to your web application, sh'ld be also set in server's config.rb,
# option "working_directory". Rack's config.ru is located here.
APP_ROOT=/home/rails/myapp/current

# Server's config.rb, it's not a rack's config.ru
CONFIG_RB=/etc/unicorn.conf

# Where to store PID, sh'ld be also set in server's config.rb, option "pid".
PID=/home/rails/myapp/current/pids/unicorn.pid
RAILS_ENV="production"
UNICORN_OPTS="-D -c $CONFIG_RB -E $RAILS_ENV"

PATH=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/
export GEM_HOME=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0
export GEM_PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global
DAEMON=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/wrappers/unicorn
```

Here's my /etc/unicorn.conf file:

```
listen "unix:/var/run/unicorn.sock"
worker_processes 4
user "rails"
working_directory "/home/rails/myapp/current"
pid "/var/run/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "/var/log/unicorn/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "/var/log/unicorn/unicorn.log"
```

Any Ideas? I feel like I have tried everything.

Answer (score 2):

Try running the following before starting unicorn:

```
gem install rack
```

Answer (score 0):

If your **RUBY VERSION** is <= `2.2.2`

then run the following commands:

```
gem install rubygems-update
update_rubygems
```

then run: `gem install rack` and it will display the version supported that you should be installing.